# How to create a required JSON for a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

This my view Html table. I am lacking in json making and I don't know how to populate it by JavaScript because outlet name has column span also.

[image: View HTML table]

I am creating HTML table from a JSON data. I am stuck with what should be the format of my table. Please see the new image:

[image: like this is my database table]

and I want to make it like

[image: I want to make it like this one]

I have created a JSON format for this like below

```
[
                      {
                            "Billdate": "01-08-18",
                            "Total": "90",
                            "Ol1-total": "20",
                            "c1": "2",
                            "c2": "4",
                            "c3": "6",
                            "c4": "8",
                            "Ol2-total": "36",
                            "c1": "10",
                            "c2": "12",
                            "c3": "14",
                            "Ol3-total": "34",
                            "c2": "16",
                            "c3": "18"
                          },
                          {
                            "Billdate": "02-08-18",
                            "Total": "150",
                            "Ol1-total": "66",
                            "c1": "20",
                            "c2": "22",
                            "c3": "0",
                            "c4": "24",
                            "Ol-total": "54",
                            "c1": "26",
                            "c2": "28",
                            "c3": "0",
                            "Ol-total": "30",
                            "c2": "22",
                            "c3": "30"
                          }
                        ]
```

But it's not a valid JSON because the key is not unique in this. How or what format of JSON should I design or should I change the view of table? I am not able to do the both.

I am posting my JavaScript code by which I am populating my table:

```
 function addTable() {
         var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);     // get all the keys from first object


             var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;        
            var num = col.splice(0, countNum);                            
            col = col.concat(num); 



                                                                        // shift the first item to last
                                                                        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

                                                        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                       // TABLE ROW.


      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");             // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

                                                            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

                                                              // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}


         addTable()
```

Comment: you can't have one key more than once in json object. It will override the previous one. in your sample `c1, c2...` are repeated.

Comment: @AagamJain yup thats my question..so how can i do this ..what should be the type of my table here then..i am confused here

Comment: You can arrange it in couple of ways. giving you some sample in answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182423/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-aagam-jain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try and let me know of any concerns.

```js
data = [{
    "amount": 49644,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "North Indian",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 194495,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 80768,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 60878,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 81999,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 8642,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 53822,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 15339,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 7548,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 15432,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 107602,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 7711,
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 39,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "North Indian",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 118647,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 119871,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "South Indian-2-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 109527,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64771,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78037,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 20261,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 69946,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18197,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 8741,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18820,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78537,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 5060,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49096,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58477,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49933,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 9915,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 51209,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 2566,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
];

function formatData(data) {
  let toReturn = [];
  let dateWiseObj = {};
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]]) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]] = [];
    }
    if (maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].indexOf(d["counter"]) == -1) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].push(d["counter"]);
    }

    if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]]) {
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
    } else {
      if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]]) {
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
      } else {
        if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]]) {
          dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
        }
      }
    }

  });

  return {
    dateWiseObj: dateWiseObj,
    maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
  };
};


function addTable(dataObj) {
  let dateWiseObj = dataObj.dateWiseObj;
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = dataObj.maxUniqueForOutlets;
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Outlet";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = d;
    th.colSpan = maxUniqueForOutlets[d].length + 1;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  table.appendChild(thead);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Date";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Counter";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(k) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Total";
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    maxUniqueForOutlets[k].forEach(function(d) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = d;
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
  });
  table.appendChild(thead);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  Object.keys(dateWiseObj).forEach(function(k) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = k;
    row.appendChild(td);

    grandTotal = 0;
    outletWiseTotal = {};
    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      outletWiseTotal[d] = 0;
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        Object.keys(dateWiseObj[k][d]).forEach(function(i) {
          outletWiseTotal[d] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
        });
      }
      grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[d];
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = grandTotal;
    row.appendChild(td);

    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[d];

      row.appendChild(td);
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = dateWiseObj[k][d][i] ? dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] : "0";
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      } else {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = "0";
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      }
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    //console.log(outletWiseTotal);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  let divContainer = document.getElementById("tbl");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
}

var dataObj = formatData(data);
addTable(dataObj);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="tbl"></div>
```

Comment: yes, you can organise it more by making 'c1, c2, ...' an array. but then you need to change the logic of rendering.

Comment: i have some logic issue in my java end also ..for creating a JSON like this  is hard form me as i am very new to this. can you help me out on java end please..

Comment: And one more thing i want to apply bootstrap table but you are showing table in div tag rather then  table tag so how can i apply bootstrap class to this table  like class="table table-striped

Answer (score 2):

Each date is a key, and the value is a two dimensional array representing the counters.

I removed the totals since they are all just totals of their respective groups, and could be summed programatically. However, you could add them back in to the end/beginning if you like.

```
{
  '01-08-18': [['2', '4', '6', '8'], ['10', '12', '14'], ['16', '18']],
  '02-08-18': [['20', '22', '0', '24'], ['26', '28', '0'], ['22', '30']]
}
```

Here's a solution to the javascript:

```js
'use strict'
const testdata = {
  '01-08-18': [['2', '4', '6', '8'], ['10', '12', '14'], ['16', '18']],
  '02-08-18': [['20', '22', '0', '24'], ['26', '28', '0'], ['22', '30']]
}

const table = document.getElementById('table')

// Create header, considering only first element from table
const firstKey = Object.keys(testdata)[0]
const header = document.getElementById('tableheader')
// add total th
const totalth = document.createElement('th')
totalth.innerHTML = "Row Total"
header.append(totalth)


for (let i = 0; i < testdata[firstKey].length; i++) {
  const O = document.createElement('th')
  O.innerHTML = `O${i + 1} total`
  header.append(O)
  for (let j = 0; j < testdata[firstKey][i].length; j++) {
    const th = document.createElement('th')
    th.innerHTML = `c${j + 1}`
    header.append(th)
  }
}

// Fill in the data
let i = 0
for (let key in testdata) {
  const row = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))
  let datetd = document.createElement('td')
  datetd.innerHTML = key
  row.append(datetd)
  //apend this rows total so we can update it after the loop
  const rowtotaltd = document.createElement('td')
  row.append(rowtotaltd)
  let rowTotal = 0
  testdata[key].map(ol => {
    // add total
    const total = ol.reduce((sum, current) => sum + parseInt(current), 0)
    rowTotal += total
    const totaltd = document.createElement('td')
    totaltd.innerHTML = total
    row.append(totaltd)
    //add individual values
    ol.map(c => {
      const td = document.createElement('td')
      td.innerHTML = c
      row.append(td)
    })
  })
  //update row total td
  rowtotaltd.innerHTML = rowTotal
  i++
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tr id='tableheader'>
    <th>Billdate</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no on the basis of user selection..like i have form which have from date to date and outlet...so if user selects ALL then all thre will be on html table otherwise if user select ol1 or ol2 the on that basis table willbe formed.....and right now i am having 3 ols but in future it can be 4-5 any no.

Comment: i just want to populate a html table.. i want just a modified table which would have alll the data i have required.

Comment: @manishthakur I've made a partial example of how you could solve this. I changed the json again.

Comment: you are only showing amount here  what about counter name and outlet names... i am totally confused here.... :(..each counters have some values also

Comment: @manishthakur You'll still need to add the header. Loop through the elements, keep track of the count and increment it. Since you have an array for each group of "O" values, you know how many "O"s there are. And since you have a value for each "c" value you know how many "c's there are. You only need to look at the first element to make the header, since you must have the same number of columns on every row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182412/discussion-between-michael-mcquade-and-manish-thakur).